# To use a part of HTML code of one angular component in another

Tags: html, angular

I have an angular component with code looks like

```
main component.html
<html>
   <div1>
     some elements
   </div1>
       <div2>
         some elements
       </div2>
```

I just want to use div1 in another component, is that possible

in child component I Should have

```
<html>
<div1>
  some elements
</div1> ////from main component 
<div2>
some elements
</div2>
<div3>
```

some elements

Answer (score 0):

You should import the component or the css file where you defined `<div1>` in the component where you need to use it

Comment: Welcome! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and edit your answer accordingly!

Comment: thanks for answering
But how to include that imported div in html

Comment: You should defined <div1> in your global css, usually app.component.css in angular, so then you can re use this style in whichever component that you need

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: I am developing a web page
In that one component is bulky, i just need some part of html code in another component